# php artisan migrate isn't working

Tags: php, laravel-5, migrate, artisan-migrate

When I try to connect to my database i get this error

```
[PDOException]                                                               
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'loom'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

all my credentials are correct and when i change things up i get this error :

```
[PDOException]                                        
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'loomcoding'
```

Can anyone help me sort this out please

my .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=xxxx

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=cl20-loom
DB_USERNAME=loom
DB_PASSWORD=xxxx

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

my database.php file :

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'cl-loom',
        'username'  => 'loom',
        'password'  => '••••',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this error last time create a database on phpmyadmin and change only the .env file to match with you phpmyadmin details and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

It can be because the mysql service is not running or it isn't on the port 3306, in the last case you may specify the port where the mysql service is running as a attribute *port* of the *mysql* object in database.php file

Comment: im a noob at this how would I check and change the sql port to 3306 and i am using Sequel pro to see my db

Comment: You can check and change in the _my.ini_ file that's located in the mysql server installation folder

Comment: Thank you I will try it out and see what I get

Comment: can't find the file 'my.ini' anywhere @Kuki Amarilla

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `mysql` you have to create the database manually in `phpMyAdmin` or whatever software you are using for `mysql`.

And no need to change the whole `database.php` if you configure the `.env` file. Just change this line `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),` in `database.php`

> Below code is not tested

Instead, you can add `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` this line in `.env`

Comment: @techedryan If work, please don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: what do i change it to @smartrahat

Comment: @techedryan I don't get you. What are trying to do now?

Comment: I'm trying to migrate my database to a database following a tutorial online but I get the errors I showed in my post

Comment: Did you create your database in `mysql`?

Comment: How do I create a database in MySQL cause my tutorial doesn't show how to do so it skips that part :( @smartrahat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96444/discussion-between-smartrahat-and-techedryan).